# Indexing DataFrame obteined with CrossTab Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Datasets.

The first one, in the **market** variable contains a generic market trend with the following structure:

```
Date     High    Close     Volume     Open      Low
```

The second, in the **moods** variable contain for each days a few tweets with an assosiate sentiment in this structure:

```
body       date            datetime         id sentiment      time
```

So, I want to count for each days how many "Bearish" and "Bullish" sentiment there are. It works and this is my code with comments:

```
# Read the datasets
market = pd.read_csv("Datasets/SP500/aggregates.txt")
moods = pd.read_json("Datasets/DatasetStockTwits-Aggregato.json")
# Remove all null sentiments
moods = moods[moods.sentiment != "null"]
# Get a generic subsets of data for computational speed
market_tail = market.tail(100)
# For each day present in market_tail, get the same days twits
moods_tail = moods.loc[moods['date'].isin(market_tail.Date)]
# So now I count for each day how many "Bearish" and "Bullish" twits there are
sentiments_count = pd.crosstab(moods_tail['date'], moods_tail['sentiment'])

print(sentiments_count)
```

This is the results:

```
sentiment   Bearish  Bullish
date                        
2017-11-03        9       12
2017-11-05        3        6
2017-11-06       20        9
2017-11-07       16       35
```

So it work fine, but I don't understand why I cannot access to `sentiments_count.date` or `sentiments_count['date']` index.

In fact if I try somethings like this:

```
print(sentiments_count['date'])
```

I obtain: `KeyError: 'date'`

Am I missing somethings? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You cannot select it, because it is `index`, so need:

```
print(sentiments_count.index)
```

For create column from `index` need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), also for data cleaning is possible add [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for remove column name `sentiment`:

```
sentiments_count = sentiments_count.reset_index().rename_axis(None, 1)

print(sentiments_count['date'])
```

Comment: It work. Thanks dude.

Comment: @bhaskarc - yes, if need original index, but obviosly it is not necessary - need convert index to column and create default index.